# Set text formula in a list & Dynamically execute

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lambda

I have a list with two columns, "ID" and "Formula," with over 100 different formulas. The "ID" column contains unique identifiers, and the "Formula" column contains mathematical expressions like "A+B*C" or "A/C."

My goal is to create a dynamic system where, in an input sheet, I can paste a list of IDs and their associated required values to calculate the output for the corresponding formulas.

I've attempted to use the LAMBDA function within the first sheet, linking IDs and formulas. However, I'm facing challenges in dynamically populating the formulas and calculating the results. Any help or guidance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: did a bit of googling and I think it is not possible using excel functions but possible using macro.

Comment: Use `LAMBDA()` named function to name manager with your ID and then call those ID to evaluate formulas assigned against those IDs.

Comment: You can either use `EVALUATE()` within a `LAMBDA()` using name manager which will trigger your workbook to be saved as a macro-enabled workbook. Or one other possible solution is using `PY()` function which might nog yet be available to you?